# what is the best way to make chat system between laravel dashboard and flutter app

Tags: laravel, flutter, chat, real-time

I Am working on project contain dashboard(laravel) and mobile app (Flutter)
There is a chat interface in the mobile application to talk with the admin on the dashboard
I searched for the appropriate way to do this, but I did not find a solution that works for me
What is the best way to implement the required real-time chat and in the least possible time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `WebSockets` for real time data sharing. Consider `socket.io`. It is a performant solution to go with. If it feels like a tough thing (it's not actually), go with `polling` method.

`Polling` means, you'll send request to server every X seconds from client. This request should fetch the messages data and populate in fluuter.

This polling should be implemented in both clients Flutter app and Admin dashboard (using javascript).

Comment: is (webSockets OR Socket.io) Still support Flutter???